# Delete all empty dirs but keep root dir

Tags: shell, find

I want to delete all empty directories in `cache`, so I do

```
find cache -empty -type d -delete
```

But this deletes the `cache` dir also. What is the clearest way to write this so that only subdirs are deleted?

Comment: You could exclude directories named `cache` with `-not -name cache`, but that would also skip a nested directory named `cache`; can you `cd` into `cache` first? Then you could run `find . -empty -type d -delete` in there.

Comment: Thanks, the `cd` solution is a clean solution @BenjaminW. Want to write a quck answer for digital karma?

Comment: I like William's answer which does it even more cleanly, actually :)

Comment: True, if it worked for me!

Comment: Oh, it looks like `-depth` with a number is BSD (macOS) `find` specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, there is `-mindepth 1` which does exactly what I want. Weird I didn't see that the first time around in the man page.

```
find cache -mindepth 1 -empty -type d -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find cache -type d -empty -depth +0 -delete
```

seems to work.

Comment: I get `find: paths must precede expression: +0` using `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
`

Comment: `-depth +0` seems to be BSD/macOS specific.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my quick test, it seems that this happens when you only have empty directories/subdirs in cache -- and so the last step finds that cache is empty and deletes it.

My solution would be a for loop:

```
for dir in `ls cache`; do find cache/$dir  -empty -type d -delete; done
```

Comment: This should really be `for dir in cache/*/` instead of parsing `ls`, which breaks for any names with blanks and shell special characters in them (see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: Thanks, that's an obvious possibility, but I was hoping there'd be a flag that does this. Like `-min-depth` or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
init () {

find cache -empty -type d > stack

cat > edprint+.txt << EOF
1p
q
EOF

cat > edpop+.txt << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

ed -s stack < edpop+.txt

next
}

end () {
rm -v ./edprint+.txt
rm -v ./edpop+.txt
exit 0
}

next () {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
end
}

main () {
line=$(ed -s stack < edprint+.txt)
rm -rfv "${line}"
ed -s stack < edpop+.txt
}

init
```

The first thing this does is save the list of empty directories to a file.  It then uses Ed to delete the first entry in the file, which would be the cache directory itself.

After that, the top line is printed from the file at a time with ed, the directory name from the file is stored in the ${line} variable, and then rf is used to delete it.  The top line in the file is then deleted with ed, (reducing the line count by 1) and the loop restarts.  When the stack file is empty, the script exits.

Comment: Wow, that escalated quickly!

Comment: I hope this isn't too long.  I like using ed like this myself, but I've been yelled at a bit here recently.  I think it works, though.

Comment: I missed the last init command too.  I always do that.  Sorry.  It will work now.

Comment: As a work of art, it is fine. As a practical solution it fails the WTF test: https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/

Answer (score 0):

Or you could let shell glob expansion help you out:

```sh
find cache/* -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: This fails the second time around: `find: ‘cache/*’: No such file or directory`

Comment: @sba That means all contents have been deleted.

Comment: This could theoretically run into a problem if `cache/*` expands to enough entries to make the command line too long.